# YouTube- video speed change

Tags: youtube

There is an option in YouTube player that you can change the speed of the video and I am wondering is there any way to add a new speed to that menu e.g. 1.1x speed?

Comment: You cannot alter the YouTube player itself or the menus. You could use the YouTube API and make your own though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playback-speed-co/hdannnflhlmdablckfkjpleikpphncik/related?hl=en-US)

[image]

If this is not what you are looking for, then you have your answer from @MC10 above in comments